# Translate Keras model to PyTorch: is my implementation correct?

Tags: keras, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tf.keras, modelsummary

I would like to translate a Keras model of a Convolutional Recurrent Neural Network (CRNN) to PyTorch.

This is the implementation of the Keras model:

```
def define_network(self):
    pool_shapes = [[5,1], [4,1], [2,1]]

    input_data_1 = Input(shape=(1500, 40, 1))
    x = input_data_1
    
    for i in range(3):
        x = Conv2D(data_format="channels_last",
               filters=64,
               kernel_size=(3,3),     
               kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform",
               activation='linear',
               padding="same",
               strides=(1,1)),
               dilation_rate=1,
               use_bias=True)(x)
        x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
        x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(tuple(pool_shapes[i])),
                         strides=None, padding='valid', data_format='channels_first')(x)
                     
    z = TimeDistributed(Flatten())(x)

    z = GRU(64, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True)
    z = Dropout(0.3)(z)
    z = GRU(64, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True)
    z = Dropout(0.3)(z)
    predictions = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))(z)

    self._network = Model([input_data_1], predictions)
    self._network.summary()
```

The summary of the Keras model which gets as input a batch `x` of tensors with dimension `x_shape=(None, 1500, 40, 1)`:

[image]

I tried to replicate it in PyTorch in this way:

```
class NeuralNetwork(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self,
        params=None,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.params = params

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 64, (3, 3), padding=1)
        self.norm = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
        self.relu = nn.LeakyReLU(0.3)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(1, 5), stride=(1, 5))
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, (3, 3), padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 64, (3, 3), padding=1)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(1, 4), stride=(1, 4))
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(1, 2), stride=(1, 2))
        self.timedistributedflatten = TimeDistributed(nn.Flatten())
        self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size=64, hidden_size=64, num_layers=1, batch_first=True)
        self.timedistributedlinear = TimeDistributed(nn.Linear(64, 1))
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform(self.conv1.weight)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform(self.conv2.weight)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform(self.conv3.weight)
        nn.init.zeros_(self.conv1.bias)
        nn.init.zeros_(self.conv2.bias)
        nn.init.zeros_(self.conv3.bias)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.norm(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.norm(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.norm(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.pool3(x)
        x = self.timedistributedflatten(x)
        x = x.permute(0, 2, 1)
        x = self.gru(x)[0]
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.gru(x)[0]
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.timedistributedlinear(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(x)
        x = x.permute(0, 2, 1)
```

where:

- `x` is the batch of tensors with dimension `x_shape=(None, 1, 1500, 40)`
- The Keras TimeDistributed` layer has not a PyTorch equivalent, therefore, I used [this implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1927#issuecomment-1245392571)

The training of the Keras model goes well, whereas the training with the PyTorch model is not; therefore, I was wondering if my PyTorch implementation is correct; the summary it produces is:

```
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
            Conv2d-1         [-1, 64, 1500, 40]             640
       BatchNorm2d-2         [-1, 64, 1500, 40]             128
         LeakyReLU-3         [-1, 64, 1500, 40]               0
           Dropout-4         [-1, 64, 1500, 40]               0
         MaxPool2d-5          [-1, 64, 1500, 8]               0
            Conv2d-6          [-1, 64, 1500, 8]          36,928
       BatchNorm2d-7          [-1, 64, 1500, 8]             128
         LeakyReLU-8          [-1, 64, 1500, 8]               0
           Dropout-9          [-1, 64, 1500, 8]               0
        MaxPool2d-10          [-1, 64, 1500, 2]               0
           Conv2d-11          [-1, 64, 1500, 2]          36,928
      BatchNorm2d-12          [-1, 64, 1500, 2]             128
        LeakyReLU-13          [-1, 64, 1500, 2]               0
          Dropout-14          [-1, 64, 1500, 2]               0
        MaxPool2d-15          [-1, 64, 1500, 1]               0
          Flatten-16                 [-1, 1500]               0
          Flatten-17                 [-1, 1500]               0
  TimeDistributed-18             [-1, 64, 1500]               0
              GRU-19  [[-1, 1500, 64], [-1, 2, 64]]               0
          Dropout-20             [-1, 1500, 64]               0
              GRU-21  [[-1, 1500, 64], [-1, 2, 64]]               0
          Dropout-22             [-1, 1500, 64]               0
           Linear-23                    [-1, 1]              65
           Linear-24                    [-1, 1]              65
  TimeDistributed-25              [-1, 1500, 1]               0
================================================================
Total params: 75,010
Trainable params: 75,010
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 0.23
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 30.73
Params size (MB): 0.29
Estimated Total Size (MB): 31.24
----------------------------------------------------------------
```